# JMeter response to a file (append it to only one file)

Tags: java, jmeter

In my JMeter project I make a request and I get a response like `{id="fklajdlfja"}` and then I get one JSON file for each response.

My question is, is there an elegant way to merge all the ids in a file?
My options are:

1. Make a JavaScript after using JMeter to put all together.
2. A JSON post-processor to get the id and then append to a file

Any nicer solution?

Comment: How are you getting id from json?

Comment: That is the response from my server. I can get the id from inside the file or put in the filename.

Comment: Can you provide response sample please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the id from response, you can either use regular expression extractor or json post processor.
Use Beanshell Post processor and append these id's into a file. That should be easiest way.